# redux state for minor action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Says I have a todo list, after a todo is created I want to save the item into localstorage. How would the reducer look like? Should I do the setItem method in reducer or in the view?

```
case 'PUBLISH_TODO_PENDING':
            return { ...state, loading: true, todo_published: false, //do I do this? }
        case 'PUBLISH_TODO_FULFILLED':

          return { 
                ...state, 
                loading: false,
                todo_published: true, //do I do this?
                data: {
                    result: {
                         todo: state.data.todo,
                    }
                }
            }
```

If I want to use setItem in view the I have to do a flag telling the stat of the todo wether is published or not. It's silly I have to put the flag in initial state too.

Answer (score 4):

You should use redux-thunk. In order to use it in your react app, use following snippet in your store.

```
const configureStore = (initialState) => (
    createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    )
)
```

Moreover, it is a better practice to write the code involving setting and getting from local storage in a separate folder, say 'utils' and import the same in your action page inside the action.

Comment: I don't see any localstorage code in above, where does the localstorage util be placed? within createStore's param?

Comment: The above code snippet is to enable use of redux-thunks in your actions. You can create the folder 'utils' inside the folder 'src' (assuming you used create-react-app). Inside the the utils folder you can create file containing the all the functionalities involving local storage.

Comment: what is thunk here (the param passed to applyMiddleware.

Answer (score 0):

Saving to localstorage is a Side Effect, which is great to handle using [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) so you listen for a particular action and you do your stuff kind of like event listener.